# distance between two eigen vectors corresponding to two different matrices in a normed space

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices. Let

1) $Ax = \lambda x$ and 
2) $By=\mu y$

for $x,y$ in a normed space. $\lambda, \mu$ are scalar. Also, for $x,y$ are unique eigen vectors (upto a multiplicative constant) for the eigen values $\lambda, \mu$.

For eigen values there are spectral variation bounds available (Rajendra Bhatia's book)

What can we tell about upper bound of $\|x-y\|$ ?

Comment: I think my example that follows will show that the answer has to depend on $||x||$ and $||y||$, if there is much to be said. Take the case $n=2$ for example, and take $A$ and $B$ to be the matrices representing projection onto the first and second coordinates, respectively. Then the vectors $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ are eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$ respectively, for any $x$ and $y$. You can then make $x$ and $y$ as large as you want and the distance between them will grow to infinity.

Comment: there's a serious answer, that is a corollary of Bauer-Fike

Comment: There's no relationship between $A$ and $B$? So you're just asking if there's a upper bound for the distance between *any two* eigenvectors, of *different* matrices?

Comment: Consider $B=\pm A$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: What's the title of Rajendra's book?

Comment: @Exodd: Matrix Analysis. Pl. check page no. chapter VIII

Comment: If you notice, in chapter VIII Rajendra always talks about the distance between the spectra of the matrices, so he never finds an upper bound of the difference between two generic eigenvalues. For example, his Theorem  VIII.3.9 and 3.10 are corollaries of my answer below

Comment: @Exodd: In special cases for example if the eigen values are Perron-Frobenious eigen-values then the difference is upper bounded by the L.H.S of the inequality in the book.

Comment: the perron-frobenius eigenvalues are the spectral values of the matrices, so that result is also a corollary of my result, since if you take $\lambda$ the bigger of the two eigenvalues, the best $\mu$ is the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A - B = F$, and suppose that $B$ is diagonalizable with $B = SDS^{-1}$ and $D$ diagonal. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a vectorial norm such that for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $y$ defined as $y_i = |x_i|\,\,\forall i$, then $\|x\| = \|y\|$.

Under these hypotesis, the [Bauer-Fike Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%E2%80%93Fike_theorem) assure us that

> for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, there exists an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $B$ such that
>   $$|\lambda-\mu | \le \|F\|\|S\|\|S^{-1}\|$$

A corollary of this theorem states that, under the same hypotesis,

> Let $u$ be an eigenvector of $A$, of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then there exists an eigenvector $v$ of $B$, with eigenvalue $\mu$, such that
>   $$
> \frac{\|u-v\|}{\|u\|} \le \|(B-\mu I)^+\|(\|F\|+|\lambda-\mu|)
> $$
>   where $(B-\mu I)^+$ is the  [Generalized Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).

In particular, if $B$ is symmetric, then it implies that

$$
\frac{\|u-v\|_2}{\|u\|_2} \le \frac{2}{\min_{t\in\sigma(B), t\ne \mu}|t-\mu|}\|F\|_2
$$
where $\sigma(B)$ is the set of $B$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, here $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are any two eigen values for $A$, $B$. For eigen values there are spectral variation bound available. But, I am interested in eigen vectors. Pl. see my edit

Comment: I am interested in reading about the proofs of the claims in this answer. What references do you recommend?