# Eigenvalue perturbation of singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Consider a Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{A_0} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ with one singularity, i.e. its eigenvalues in increasing order are:
\begin{equation}
0 < \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_N
\end{equation}
The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_k$ is $\mathbf{v_k}$.
Now consider a matrix with small entries $\mathbf{\delta A}$ and $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A_0} + \mathbf{\delta A}$, let the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ be 
\begin{equation}
\gamma_1 \leq \gamma_2 \leq  \cdots \leq \gamma_N
\end{equation}
The eigenvector corresponding to $\gamma_k$ is $\mathbf{u_k}$.
It is well-known that a $1^{st}$ order perturbation of eigenvalues is
\begin{equation}
\gamma_k = \lambda_k +\mathbf{v_k^H} \mathbf{\delta A} \mathbf{v_k} + O(\delta^2)
\end{equation}
There is also a similar expression of $\mathbf{u_k}$ as a function of $\mathbf{v_1} \ldots \mathbf{v_k}$.

The questions are:

1) Is this true for $k = 1$, i.e. can we say $\gamma_1 =  \mathbf{v_1^H} \mathbf{\delta A} \mathbf{v_1} + O(\delta^2)$ ? The reason i'm asking this is that i see repeatedly that the matrix $\mathbf{A_0}$ should be positive definite so that the perturbation on eigenvalues hold true.

2) If (1) is true, can we approximate $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ by $\frac{1}{\gamma_1}\mathbf{u_1}\mathbf{u_1^H} $ ? Is there any formal theory behind this apprxoimation ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean by "one singularity" that $\lambda_1=0$ and  $Ker(A)=\mathbb{v_1}$ for a certain $v_1 \neq 0$ ? And that when you say, at the end that $A^{-1}$ is approximated by... it means that the pseudo-inverse $A^+$ IS $\frac{1}{\gamma_1}\mathbf{u_1}\mathbf{u_1^H}$?

Comment: Hi JeanMarie, 
For the first part of your question, yes "one singularity" is what you just said. 
For the second part, no i mean $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, what happens if i say pseudo-inverse ?

Comment: But the problem is that $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ doesn't exist because of this eigenvalue $0$...

Comment: Hi again, well 0 is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A_0}$ and not $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have watched...

Comment: Has your issue a connection with the Bauer Fike theorem for eigenvalues perturbation ? See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1838485)

Comment: [This thread](http://mathoverflow.net/q/116123) on MO may be helpful. In your case, if $\delta A$ is Hermitian and $\delta A=f(\delta)$ for some analytic $f$, then the smallest eigenvalue of $A_0+\delta A$ is analytic too when $\delta$ is small (at least before any eigenvalue crossing). Hence the error term must be bounded by some sort of second-order term.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi You said a similar expression exists for eigenvectors as well. May I know what is that expression for eigenvectors and where can I find it.